# Display dialog box

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
          <body>
       <script>
         $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#mybutton").click(function(){

        $("#dbox").dialog({

         title:'form',


        width:600,
        height:600,
        modal:true,

       });
           });
                });
         </script>

     <div id="dbox">
      <form>
        Your Name<input type="text"     name="text">
       Email:<input type="text" name="text"     placeholder="Email">

     </form>
    </div>
    <input type="submit" id="mybutton" value="Individuals">
 </body>
```

Here While loading the page form appears.So how to solve that.I        have used jquery to display dialog box on click event.Dialog box appears on click event but when the page is loaded there form appears on the page also.I dont get how to avoid it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hide the box initialy, adding `style = "display:none"`.

```
 <div id="dbox" style = "display:none">
      <form>
        Your Name<input type="text"     name="text">
       Email:<input type="text" name="text"     placeholder="Email">

     </form>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can simply like this you need to hide the form on page load try below code

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#dbox").hide();
    $("#mybutton").click(function(){
        $("#dbox").dialog({
         title:'form',
        width:600,
        height:600,
        modal:true,
       });
           });
                });
         </script>
```